# Translating Mobile PSD to html which length unit should we use vh,%,px

Tags: css, responsive-design

[image: Mobile Design]

For responsive web design which length(height/width) unit we should use.
I have been given attached image where all the measurement are in px.
So I started with px only but it didn't work. Due to that I consider attached image for Iphone6(375x667) and started calculating  width,height by multiplying single unit 1/375(width),1/667(height ) with number of pixel given in image.

Same thing I am doing with margin, padding, border value.

Want to know am I  going in right direction or need to do something else for responsive mobile development?

CSS for 1st block :
height=1/667*58vh;
width=1/ 375*370vw;

Answer (score 0):

The width is just 100% so that must not be calculated. For the height you don't need to use the viewport height of a specific device because not all people use an iPhone 6. For the first block you just set the height to 58vh and that's it. You can use flexbox to center everything so that you don't have to use padding.
Take into account that this will look horrible on landscape.

Comment: for width you are right I simply use 100% but do you think 58vh for 58px is right way. Landscape mode we are going to disable

Comment: You're right, 58vh is 58% of the viewport height, my mistake. You will have to calculate the vh by using a reference height like you did for example the  iPhone 6. The chances that the outcome will be 58px is slim (except on iPhone 6), but that's what you get with responsive design. The calculation would be (58/667)*100. This will give you (rounded) a vh of 8.7

Comment: for font-size what I should do.I am using rem currently and giving base font size in px at html{32px} like this

Comment: Is 32px not a bit high? What I usually do is put the font-size on the html to 62.5% (~10px). This makes it easier for you to think in px when you use rem or em because 1em will equal ~10px. You can also make the font-size responsive to the vh. See this example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/jLe8p588/1/